# Filepaths in PHP

Tags: php, file

I'm uploading a video to a local folder on my Development Site and storing in the DB the post_media_path.. It looks as follows :

```
media/pages/2/posts/post-video-1456829306.mp4
```

I am then trying to upload the video using Vimeo. However Vimeo is coming back with an error "Unable to locate file".

So I'm trying this :

```
$filePath = getcwd() .'/'. $data['post_media_path'];
```

But when I do that, The path comes up as follows :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\sd-tools\public/media/pages/2/posts/post-video-1456829306.mp4
```

I suspect the path is wrong due to the \'s and /'s being the wrong way round.

How do I go about fixing this or getting this to work?

Thanks

Comment: The code might actually work fine on linux

Comment: Hi @aron9forever currently working on a Windows Machine, But site will be hosted on a linux server. So will try this on a live URL / Hosted account. Cheers

Comment: I wrote a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is caused by the way you're storing your `post_media_path`

Usually paths in linux look like `/home/user/` while on windows `C:\user\`

So ideally you'd need to store your values according to what OS you're running on.

A quick fix is

```
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN')
{
    //if running on windows
    $filePath = getcwd() .'\'. str_replace("/", "\", $data['post_media_path']);
}
else
{
    //if running on something else than windows
    $filePath = getcwd() .'/'. $data['post_media_path'];
}
```

which will do what you're currently doing under linux, but replace `/` with `\` under windows. However for this not to cause any issues, you need to make sure that the filename itself doesn't contain `/`.